# How to build valid identifier names in golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to use one the functionality provided by go linter in my code. If you use a name like `GetId` or `ServiceUrl` in go, the linter warns you that the name should be `GetID` or `ServiceURL`. How could I achieve the same thing in my code.
For example if in my I code I have a string `GetId`, how could I convert it to a golang compatible identifier (in this case `GetID`).

Answer (score 5):

The names `GetId`, `getId` and `ServeURL` are all valid, they just don't follow style [guidelines](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments).  The name `getId` should be changed to `getID` to follow the guidelines.  See the [initialisms](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) section of guidelines for more information about these names.

The [lint package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/lint) does not provide an API to get the replacement text for an identifier. It is, however, possible to construct a source file with the identifier, feed it to the linter and parse the problem. Something like this:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/lint"
    "strings"
)

func checkName(s string) (string, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "// Package main is awesome\npackage main\n// %s is wonderful\nvar %s int\n", s, s)
    var l lint.Linter
    problems, err := l.Lint("", buf.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if len(problems) >= 1 {
        t := problems[0].Text
        if i := strings.Index(t, " should be "); i >= 0 {
            return t[i+len(" should be "):], nil
        }
    }
    return "", nil
}
```

The function call `checkName("getId")` returns `"getID"`.

Comment: You're right! Given a string, how can I programatically transform it into another string which follows the guidelines?

Comment: That first sentence is super important. Don't mistake "best practice" for "valid".